# In SyncAdapter, Im calling requestSync but onPerfomSync is not calling

Tags: android, synchronization

i'm desperate,
can anyone help to fix this?
in SyncAdapter, i'm calling requestSync but onPerfomSync is not calling!
 here is the code i've used:

my Onchange method is calling Correctly and i'm requesting for sync by requestSync but onPerformChange never called,

```
private class ContentObserverCLS extends ContentObserver {

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        final SessionManagement management = new SessionManagement(
                getApplicationContext());


            final Account account = new Account(management.getUserDetail()
                    .getUserName().toString(),
                    "com.myapp.account");

            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            ContentResolver.requestSync(account,
                    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, bundle);
        }
    }

}

public static class SyncAdapterImpl extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;

    public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context) {
        super(context, true);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras,
            String authority, ContentProviderClient provider,
            SyncResult syncResult) {
        //TODO

    }
}

private static SyncAdapterImpl sSyncAdapter = null;
private static ArrayList<MobileContactInfo> phoneContacts;

public static void run(Context context, ServiceConnection connection) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, ContactsSyncAdapterService.class);
    // Set the general action.
    i.setAction("ACTION_START");
    // Request to start.
    context.startService(i);
}

private ContentObserverCLS observerCLS;
private static SoapReceiveRequest getNewMobileContacts;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    IBinder ret = null;
    ret = sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    observerCLS = new ContentObserverCLS(handler);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, observerCLS);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: could my problem be my added ACCOUNT?

Comment: For account use  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: but, my adapter is not syncable="true",
 also i diden't set setIsSyncable() to my account, because when ever i do that, my onChange method in ContentObserver class stops working.

Comment: Then problem is in your account. Cross check---> ContactsContract.AUTHORITY

Comment: Okay i think your right, im setting 
setIsSyncable(myAccount, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1), but when i getIsSyncable this account, it returns -1